# How to let a position-absolute div maintain its postion on document resize

Tags: html, css, position

I have a a div with following css

```css
.menu{ 
    width:auto; 
    background-color:#FFF; 
    z-index:14; 
    position:absolute; 
    border:1px solid #d7d7d7; 
    border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;   
    display:none; 
    height:auto; 
    padding-top:2px; 
    padding-bottom:2px;  
}
```

When you click on the required element, i position this div according the left and top offset of the element clicked.

When the document inreases in height from the top, this div doesn't change its position accordingly. This makes it look very bad.

How do i maintain its position in such cases

Comment: please show the html, or relevant fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to wrap your `.menu` with `div wrapper`

html

```
<div class="mainWrap">
  <div class="menu"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.mainWrap {
 position:relative;
}

.menu{ 
    width:auto; 
    background-color:#FFF; 
    z-index:14; 
    position:absolute; 
    border:1px solid #d7d7d7; 
    border-bottom:2px solid #ccc;   
    display:none; 
    height:auto; 
    padding-top:2px; 
    padding-bottom:2px;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you position an element using `absolute`, it will calculate the offset based on the first ancestor with positioning (this means `position: absolute;` or `position: relative`).

```
<body>
  <div id="parent1">
    <div id="child1" style="position: absolute"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent2" style="position: relative;">
    <div id="child2" style="position: absolute;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="parent3" style="position: absolute;">
    <div id="child3" style="position: absolute;"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

`child1` calculates the offset from the `body` bacause it's parent doesn't have positioning. `child2` and `child3` calculate their offset from their parents, because `parent2` and `parent3` have positioning.

For more information, check the [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#absolute-positioning) about absolutely positioning, relative positioning and floats.

Answer (score 0):

Need a fiddle. But I would say use position:relative instead of position:absolute in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got position: relative; on the parent element?